# How to get LaTeX-style verbatim/ttt text in Matplotlib axis labels?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to get some LaTeX-style verbatim text `that looks, for example, like this` in an axis label with Matplotlib.  How would I do this?

Comment: In how far is this a problem? Can you [edit] your question to include what you have tried and in how far it doesn't meet your expectations?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I haven't tried anything because I can't find anything to try.  I've Googled around but can't find anything.  Right now Matplotlib is just using a "normal" font to write axis labels.  My expectations are being met 0% because I have literally nothing happening towards this end.

Answer (score 0):

To make the axis label appear in a monospace font, you can use the monospace font family.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

font = FontProperties()
font.set_family("monospace")

plt.plot([2,1,3])
plt.xlabel("That is verbatim", fontproperties=font)
plt.ylabel("That is normal")

plt.show()
```

[image]